Angular 12 production build issue: Optimization error Cannot negate a statement
I am doing angular upgrade from 9 to 12. On angular 9 , Ivy was off, so during upgraded , I was able to reach angular 12. Everything is working fine.
Ng serve and ng build --prod with optimization off. But the minute I turn on optimization flag to true, I start getting weird error which is not giving me anything
Error: Optimization error [901-es2018.43c67daca185cb9cbc0c.js]: Error: Cannot negate a statement
at AST_ClassExpression. (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:13612:15)
at AST_ClassExpression.negate (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:13666:21)
at C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:20132:24
at AST_Conditional.optimize (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:17319:19)
at Compressor.before (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:17304:24)
at AST_Conditional.transform (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6613:41)
at C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6677:45
at Compressor.before (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:17299:9)
at AST_Return.transform (C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6613:41)
at C:\Gurp_Code\Development\WurkNowWebApp\WurkNowApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6629:21
I can really use the help as I am stuck for days on this. I have lots of third party libraries but I am not getting any issue on compiling.

Upgrading third party library to ivy compatible version
Searched online for updating terser to new version

Package.json
{
"name": "wurk-now-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --hmr",
"build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --aot=false --build-optimizer=false",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr",
"postinstall": "ngcc"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.18",
"@angular/animations": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/common": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/compiler": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/core": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/forms": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/localize": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/router": "^12.2.17",
"@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
"@ngui/auto-complete": "^3.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^6.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^5.2.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^5.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^5.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^2.3.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.7.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^7.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "6.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^4.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^5.4.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^5.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.4",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.11.0",
"@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.0",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.41.2",
"@progress/telerik-angular-report-viewer": "^9.20.219",
"@types/ej.web.all": "^16.4.3",
"angular-croppie-module": "0.0.7",
"angular-mydatepicker": "^0.5.1",
"angular2-signaturepad": "^4.0.2",
"angularx-social-login": "^3.5.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"croppie": "^2.6.4",
"ej-angular2": "^17.3.26",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
"ng-http-loader": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"rxjs": "^6.5.4",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
"sendbird": "^3.0.61",
"signalr": "^2.4.1",
"syncfusion-javascript": "^17.3.26",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18",
"@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.17",
"@angular/language-service": "^12.2.17",
"@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
"@types/croppie": "^2.5.4",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.3",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
"@types/node": "^13.9.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"terser": "^5.31.1",
"ts-node": "~8.6.2",
"typescript": "^4.3.5"
}
}
I nned any type of guidance or pointers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
